# How can I return an object of type EntityCollection for use with a SelectList in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, html-helper, enumeration

I have made an extension to `DropDownList` in the ASP.NET MVC `HtmlHelper` to make it render `optgroup`'s. It works 'fine' when the second collection is an `IList`, but I quickly found out that if it's not, or in my case if it's an `EntityCollection` it crashes because the `SelectList` is unable to enumerate it.

So, I'm here asking for help from anyone who knows how I can bypass the issue. I thought about passing in a `Type` of what the second collection is and then performing casts internally, but that just doesn't feel right...

Anyway, I hope someone can help me, here's the current code:

```
internal IList<GroupListItem> GetListItems() {
    return (from object Item in Items
            select new GroupListItem {
                Children = new SelectList((Eval(Item, this.ChildrenField) as IEnumerable), this.ChildDataValueField, this.ChildDataTextField, this.ChildSelectedValue),
                Label = (Eval(Item, this.LabelField) as string)
            }).ToList();
}

private static object Eval(
    object Container,
    string Expression) {
    object Value = Container;

    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Expression)) {
        Value = DataBinder.Eval(Container, Expression);
    };

    if (Value is IList) {
        return Value;
    };

    return Convert.ToString(Value, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using IEnumerable instead of IList?

Comment: I have, but the problem is that in this case any object that is passed in implements IEnumerable, so they will always hit that conditional and return. Non-collection objects, such as the label in this case, will never return properly and will cause problems elsewhere in the code.